# A vogal u em ceg-u-eir-a?

Tags: gramática, morfologia, fonética, derivação

No seguinte exemplo da derivação deadjectival de um nome surge a vogal **-u-**:

> Ceg-o > Ceg-**u**-eir-a

Reparem que o segmento **-eir-** é o sufixo derivacional. O segmente **-u** surge não por derivação mas por razões fonéticas para impedir que a base e o sufixo ao juntarem-se fiquem **Ceg-eir** em que o encontro **-ge-** se leria **je** pelas regras fonéticas habituais. A pergunta é pois como chamamos à vogal **-u-** neste caso e ao processo que a introduz?

Vou mencionar (embora não interfira com a pergnta e por isso podemos ignorar) que o **-o** com que termina a base derivante é o índice temático (pode ter variação de género sendo **-o** ou **-a**) que no produto derivacional fica **-a**.

Comment: Eu sei que a pergunta deve ser fácil e talvez até um duplicado, mas já procurei na gramática várias vezes e não encontro a explicação formal para isto.

Comment: Uma pista: nos verbos estas mudanças chama-se "discordância gráfica" mas não sei como chamar a isto numa derivação.

Comment: bad_coder, acho que estender o uso de *discordância gráfica* para substantivo é como estender o sentido de função para conjuntos que não sejam de apenas números,: o nome *função* por si nunca foi exclusivo de números, mesmo que tenha se usado mais assim. Ainda mais visto que «gu» pode ser visto como um único grafema.

Comment: @Schilive depois de me ter lembrado da termo "discordância gráfica" acho que também se deve aplicar na derivção e não só nos verbos, mas eu só me recordava de ter visto isto ser usado na flexão verbal. Tenho de confirmar na gramática. Também acho como dizes que "gu" conta como um único grafema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A questão que trouxe se dá por um erro de concepção muito comum: **a língua é falada, não escrita**.

O "u" antes de "g" e "q" é um artifício gráfico para nos lembrar que, em determinada palavra, estão representados os fonemas /g/ e /k/ respectivamente. Então é o contrário, usamos aquela seqüência de letras para representar a palavra, portanto o "u" não surge para impedir nada, ele surge para compensar uma mudança fonológica que ocorreu há muito tempo no latim vulgar. Este "u" surge na escrita apenas, não é um morfema, a palavra é, na realidade, /se'geira/.

Esta confusão decorre do fato de estarmos acostumados a  usar a palavra escrita com a nossa ortografia para a análise de morfemas. Assim, a palavra é simplesmente a raiz "ceg-" + o sufixo "-eira" + o índice temático "a" — o "u" aparece na ortografia apenas para mostrar que o "g" representa um /g/.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Penso que vale observar que, para o futuro desenvolvimento da língua, o papel da língua escrita talvez ganhe importância, por conta do seu uso muito mais amplo que no passado, especialmente na troca espontânea e informal de mensagens de texto (um exemplo sendo o uso oral da abreviação "LOL" que se observa em alguns países).

Comment: Sim, de certa forma. LOL é uma palavra que surgiu como um acrônimo, pode ser considerado um neologismo que surgiu na escrita mesmo!